# Boundedness of the sum of $\arctan n$

Tags: calculus, analysis, summation

Could someone please explain me why $$s_n=\sum^n_1 \arctan(k)$$ is bounded?

P.S I need it to understand something. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Btw, I assume you mean $\sum_{k=1}^n \arctan k$?

Comment: We can only explain why $s_n$ is NOT bounded.

Answer (score 3):

It is not. For large $n$, $\arctan n \approx \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, so the sum grows about linearly in $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\arctan$ is monotonically increasing so if $s_n$ is bounded then the series $\sum_n \arctan n$ is convergent and this is absurd ($\arctan n \nrightarrow0$). We can conclude.

Answer (score 1):

As $\arctan 1=\frac \pi4$ and $t\mapsto \arctan t$ is increasing, we have $s_n\geqslant n\frac{\pi}4$, so we can't hope boundedness.